# VBA - Determine Whether the Activeworkbook has a Password

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to use VBA to determine if an active workbook has a password. (It's part of a tool that checks to make sure the active workbook is safe to distribute)

What I've tried so far that hasn't worked:

- `ActiveWorkbook.Password` returns ******** regardless of what the
  active workbook's password actually is - even if the workbook does 
  not have a password.
- `ActiveWorkbook.ProtectWindows` Or `ActiveWorkbook.ProtectStructure`
  returns False even when the active workbook has a password.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `activeworkbook.protection` perhaps?

Comment: Do you mean a password on the code, or to modify the WorkBook?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A workbook object has a 'HasPassword' property you can use:

```
Public Sub TestIt()

    If ActiveWorkbook.HasPassword Then
        MsgBox "Password Protected"
    Else
        MsgBox "Not Password Protected"
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: This works only if the Workbook has a password. It's possible to protect it without a password (which seems somewhat counterintuitive)

Comment: Yes, but original question asked for an entire workbook password

Comment: Valid point. I assumed he wanted to check if a workbook was protected, but he did specifically ask about a password.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed.  Thank you Fink!

Answer (score 0):

Are you certain that the workbook has protection. I created this basic UDF to test for protection:

```
Function IsWorkbookProtected(wb As Workbook, nType As Integer) As Boolean
    IsWorkbookProtected = False

    If nType = 1 Then 'Test for protected structure
        IsWorkbookProtected = CBool(wb.ProtectStructure)
    Else ' Test for protected windows
        IsWorkbookProtected = CBool(wb.ProtectWindows)
    End If
End Function
```

And when I ran this procedure, it worked correctly:

```
Sub TestFunction()
    MsgBox (IsWorkbookProtected(ActiveWorkbook, 2))
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will test the protection and let you know what's protected (with or without a password):

```
Public Sub TestPassword()

    Dim wrkBk As Workbook
    Dim wrkSht As Worksheet

    Set wrkBk = ActiveWorkbook

    With wrkBk
        If .ProtectStructure Or .ProtectWindows Then
            MsgBox "Workbook protection"
        End If
    End With

    For Each wrkSht In wrkBk.Worksheets
        If wrkSht.ProtectContents Then
            MsgBox wrkSht.Name & " protected."
        End If
    Next wrkSht

End Sub
```

Comment: They did, which suggests the method isn't being used correctly. `MsgBox ActiveWorkbook.ProtectWindows` returns TRUE if I protect Windows while protecting the workbook.  Maybe the ActiveWorkbook isn't the file the OP is expecting while running the code - would need to see the full code before I could say.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have tested for protection you can try to unprotect the workbook without supplying a password. This will fail if the workbook is protected with a password.

```
ActiveWorkbook.Unprotect Password:=""
```

Then you can handle the error and take it from there.